# View divs when click buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see on this website http://www.templategarden.com/preview/tempo/template/index.html In the portfolio section different divs appear on clicking the buttons. And the size of the main Container also increases or decreases accordingly. I guess JS/Jquery will be required. Please help guys I am new to web development and am stuck here.

```css
    .wrap {
        max-width: 1150px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    #portone {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    
    .porttwo {
        font-size: 34px;
        color: #222222;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #portthree {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #888888;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 2.1;
    }
    
    
    /*buttons starts here*/
    
    #select {
        width: 660px;
        height: 45px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .buttonz {
        margin-left: 9px;
        padding: 10px 22px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #222222;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .buttonz:hover {
        background-color: #7cc576;
        border-color: #7cc576;
        color: #fff;
        transition: ease 0.5s;
    }
    
    
    /*buttons end here*/
    
    #portfolio_img {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .project {
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 90px;
    }
```

```html
            <section class="wrap">
            <div id="portone">
                <h1 class="porttwo" id="portfolio">portfolio</h1>
                <h3 id="portthree">Fresh portfolio designs that will keep you wanting you more.</h3> </div>
            <!--buttons starts here-->
            <div id="select">
                <input class="buttonz" name="button" type="button" value="ALL">
                <input class="buttonz" name="button" type="button" value="BRANDING">
                <input class="buttonz" name="button" type="button" value="WEB DESIGN">
                <input class="buttonz" name="button" type="button" value="PRINT DESIGN">
                <input class="buttonz" name="button" type="button" value="PHOTOGRAPHY"> </div>
            <!--buttons end here-->
            <!--portfolio images starts here-->
            <div id="portfolio_img">
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic1.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic2.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic3.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic4.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic5.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="project" src="http://planusdesign.com/images/Portfolio-pic6.jpg" alt="project-img"></a>
            </div>
            <!--portfolio images ends here -->
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS/JQ not required. Check this. U can change the attributes `all,` `web`, `app`, `brand` belonging to the list

```
<div class="item" all brand web>1</div>
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #08f;
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.item,
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

#rball:checked ~ .item[all] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rbweb:checked ~ .item[web] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rbapp:checked ~ .item[app] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rbbrand:checked ~ .item[brand] {
  display: inline-block;
}
hr {
  border: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<input name="rb" type="radio" id="rball" checked><label for="rball">All</label>
<input name="rb" type="radio" id="rbweb"><label for="rbweb">Web Design</label>
<input name="rb" type="radio" id="rbapp"><label for="rbapp">App Development</label>
<input name="rb" type="radio" id="rbbrand"><label for="rbbrand">Branding</label>
<hr>
<div class="item" all brand web>1</div>
<div class="item" all app>2</div>
<div class="item" all brand>3</div>
<div class="item" all web>4</div>
<div class="item" all app web>5</div>
<div class="item" all web>6</div>
<div class="item" all app>7</div>
<div class="item" all web>8</div>
```